# Failed to create nested elements in XML using XLST

Tags: xslt

I have a flat XML which looks like this:

```
<objectDataList>
<objectData>
    <equipment>
        <name>Chassis-One</name>
        <type>Chassis</type>
    </equipment>
</objectData>
<objectData>
    <equipment>
        <name>Shelf-One</name>
        <type>Shelf</type>
    </equipment>
</objectData>
<objectData>
    <equipment>
        <name>Shelf-Two</name>
        <type>Shelf</type>
    </equipment>
</objectData>
<objectData>
    <equipment>
        <name>Slot-One</name>
        <type>Slot</type>
    </equipment>
</objectData>
```

How can I create an XSL that will transform my XML into another XML that looks like this:

```
<equipments>
<object>
    <name>Chassis-One</name>
        <object>
            <name>Shelf-One</name>
            <object>
                <name>Slot-One</name>
            </object>
        </object>

</object>
```

It's like in a chassis, there are 2 shelves, and in Shelf One, there is Slot -One..

I tried halfway, but I couldn't think how to make the element nested:

```
<xsl:template match="/response">
    <equipments>            
            <object>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="objectData"/>
            </object>
    </equipments>
```

```
<xsl:template match="objectData/equipment[type='Chassis']">
    <name><xsl:value-of select="equipment/name"/></name>
        <!-- Now I want to find the shelf according to the chassis name -->
        <xsl:call-template name="find-shelf-according-to-chasis-name">
            <xsl:with-param name="chassisName" select="equipment/name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope someone could shed some light

Thank you in advance

Comment: Other than name convention, how should the script decide on the parent-child relation between nodes?

Comment: based on <name> = "%-One".. basically if the shelf name is Shelf-One, then it will belong under Chassis-One.. and if the slot name is SLot-One, then it will belong under Shelf-One..

Comment: In your example you place Shelf-Two under Chassis-One. Should it not be in the output if Chassic-Two is missing in the input?

Comment: oh yeah sorry, my bad.. removed. Thanks for pointing it out! :)

Comment: It's still not clear when one object should be a child of another. What determines that a shelf should be a child of a chassis, or a slot should be a child of shelf? Are there any other types?

Comment: hi Flynn1179, nope there are no other types. Basically the hierarchy is already fixed like that Chassis -> Shelf -> Slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fairly simple (although a little verbose) solution:

```
<xsl:template match="objectDataList">
  <equipments>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="objectData[equipment/type='Chassis']"/>
  </equipments>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objectData[equipment/type='Chassis']">
  <xsl:variable name="index" select="substring-after(equipment/name,'-')" />
  <object>
    <xsl:copy-of select="equipment/name" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::objectData[equipment/type='Shelf' and substring-after(equipment/name,'-') = $index]" />
  </object>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objectData[equipment/type='Shelf']">
  <xsl:variable name="index" select="substring-after(equipment/name,'-')" />
  <object>
    <xsl:copy-of select="equipment/name" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::objectData[equipment/type='Slot' and substring-after(equipment/name,'-') = $index]" />
  </object>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objectData[equipment/type='Slot']">
  <xsl:variable name="index" select="substring-after(equipment/name,'-')" />
  <object>
    <xsl:copy-of select="equipment/name" />
  </object>
</xsl:template>
```

It's a bit repetitive though, the last three templates are almost identical. But then, depending on your specific requirements, it might be helpful that they're handled by different templates.

If you can guarantee that a shelf will always follow the related chassis etc, then you can change the `<xsl:apply-templates` in the second template to:

`<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]">`

If there might not be one, then you can do:

`<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][equipment/type='Shelf']">`

Comment: Thanks Flynn1179, it works well. Yup, the chassis-shelf-slot hierarchy is fixed, therefore I changed the second template as you suggested! Thanks again :)

Comment: Cool.. if you ever get a chassis on a shelf though, you know it's not as fixed as you thought :)

Answer (score 0):

The following script will do what you want, it is a bit lengthy due to the fact that the Chassis - Shelf - Slot structure has to be represented in the script. If your xml would contain id and parent-id attributes the script could be smaller and the naming convention could be removed or loosened.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <equipments>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//equipment[type='Chassis']" />
    </equipments>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="equipment[type='Chassis']">
    <xsl:variable name="suffix" select="substring-after(name, '-')" />
    <object>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//equipment[type='Shelf'][substring-after(name, '-')=$suffix]" />
    </object>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="equipment[type='Shelf']">
    <xsl:variable name="suffix" select="substring-after(name, '-')" />
    <object>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//equipment[type='Slot'][substring-after(name, '-')=$suffix]" />
    </object>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="equipment[type='Slot']">
    <object>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
    </object>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The part you were asking for uses the `substring-after` function to determine the name suffix and uses that in the subsequent selection.

Comment: Thanks rsp, yours worked well too. Yeah too bad my original xml does not have id/parent-id attributes, it's based on name only..